# How do I prevent a ToolBar in a nested UserControl from being focused when switching tabs?

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, toolbar, tabcontrol

I wrote an example application that highlights the issue, which might have to do with focus-scope because it's whenever a ToolBar is involved and a UserControl is unloaded when switching tabs.

The main window contains a Menu with a File->New command and a TabControl that displays a collection of "Box" instances:

```
<DockPanel>
    <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <MenuItem Header="_File">
            <MenuItem Command="New"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Boxes}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="40"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:BoxView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

Each "Box" instance has a *Name* property displayed in the tab header, and the rest of it is displayed in a "BoxView" UserControl. The "BoxView" has a ToolBar, the first button of which becomes the **focus hog** in the mentioned use case. The "BoxView" also displays a collection of "Compartments" that are inside each "Box" instance:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ToolBarTray IsLocked="True">
        <ToolBar>
            <Button Content="Focus hog"/>
        </ToolBar>
    </ToolBarTray>

    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Compartments}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:CompartmentView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Each "Compartment" instance has a *TotalValue* property simply displayed in a TextBox in a "CompartmentView" UserControl:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding TotalValue}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

## And the problem is...

If I click on the TextBox of any one of the CompartmentView's, and then click a different tab of the main window, the first button of the ToolBar of the BoxView is focused (the **focus hog** one), disabling commands working in the main window.

It can be observed commands are disabled when opening the File menu. But after closing the menu and reopening, commands are enabled again.

How do I prevent the ToolBar in the nested UserControl from being focused when switching tabs?

Or perhaps I'm going at this wrong... how do I prevent focus from being set when switching tabs?

## Update

The following link is a video on youtube where I explain the problem with the application.
https://youtu.be/0T5LK3CYxgw

## Solution update

Thanks to themightylc for the answer, the issue was clearly a *keyboard focus* problem when the focused visual control (any selected "CompartmentView" or "BoxView" control) was unloaded while changing the selected tab in the TabControl. The solution was to focus on the TabControl itself in the main window whenever the tab selection changed:

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TabControl).Focus();
}
```

Thanks also to Christoph Nahr's response for the solution on this msdn thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f5de6ffc-fa03-4f08-87e9-77bbad752033/a-focusscope-nightmare-bug-commands-are-disabled?forum=wpf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Button Content="Focus hog" Focusable="False" />
```

This solves the problem you're having. `Focusable` is a DependencyProperty If you still want to access the ToolBar via Keyboard-Focus, you can bind it or set it from code-behind when the Tab-Switch is complete.

You can of course set it via Style so you don't have to set it on every element of the ToolBar.

Comment: This answers the question exactly, and helps me see the issue better. I believe the problem is when the "CompartmentView"s are unloaded, the logical focus falls to the first element. When the tab finishes loading the new "BoxView" with all its "CompartmentView"s, the first element (the **focus hog**) of the new "BoxView" was receiving focus. The complete solution would be as you recommended, _"set [the keyboard focus] from code-behind when the Tab-Switch is complete"_. Now to figure how to do that...

Comment: The final solution was setting the _keyboard focus_ to the main window's TabControl whenever the TabControl's selection changed. The problem was due to the keyboard focus being on a control that no longer existed in the visual tree when the tab was switched. This msdn thread helped: [https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f5de6ffc-fa03-4f08-87e9-77bbad752033/a-focusscope-nightmare-bug-commands-are-disabled?forum=wpf](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f5de6ffc-fa03-4f08-87e9-77bbad752033/a-focusscope-nightmare-bug-commands-are-disabled?forum=wpf)